# Javascript, return first (sub) object that matches

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of objects which I am trying to look through to grab the first child object that matches a certain object I am giving it. So my object looks like so :

```
const filteredVariants = [
{
   name: "Test0",
   images: [
   {
    name: "test0img1",
    shot_type: "swatch"
   }]
   }, {
   name: "Test1",
   images: [
   {
    name: "test1img1",
    shot_type: "product"
   },
   {
    name: "test1img2",
    shot_type: "product"
   }]
}]
```

So what I am looking to do is look through this object, specifically inside `images` and find the first object that has `shot_type: "product"` and return that. So, in this case I am trying to get it to return to me :

```
{
name: "test1img1",
shot_type: "product"
}
```

Here is what I have so far :

```
 const firstProductImage = _.find(filteredVariants, _.flow(
    _.property('images'),
    _.partialRight(_.some, { shot_type: 'product' })
 ));
```

This is partially the way there, except it's returning the entire parent object, when I just need the child image object. I have tried running over a map and filter as well, but those approaches were not as clean as this one. I am wondering if there is a way to tell lodash in this case to just return that first child node that matches `{ shot_type: 'product' }` .

I am using lodash, but if this is possible in plain javascript, that would be great too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate `filteredVariants` and `images` and if found, then assign the object to `result`. The returned truthy value ends both loops.

Version with [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
var filteredVariants = [{ name: "Test0", images: [{ name: "test0img1",  shot_type: "swatch" }]}, { name: "Test1", images: [{ name: "test1img1",  shot_type: "product" }, { name: "test1img2", shot_type: "product" }] }],
    result;

filteredVariants.some(variant =>
    variant.images.some(image => image.shot_type === "product" && (result = image))
);

console.log(result);
```

Version with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
var variants = [{ name: "Test0", images: [{ name: "test0img1",  shot_type: "swatch" }]}, { name: "Test1", images: [{ name: "test1img1",  shot_type: "product" }, { name: "test1img2", shot_type: "product" }] }],
    result = variants.reduce((r, variant) =>
        r || variant.images.find(image => image.shot_type === "product"),
        undefined
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const productImage = _.reduce(filteredVariants, (acc, item) => {
  return acc || _.find(item.images, image => image['shot_type'] === 'product')
}, undefined);
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adrice727/dua6kryd/1/

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```js
const filteredVariants = [
{
   name: "Test0",
   images: [
   {
    name: "test0img1",
    shot_type: "swatch"
   }]
   }, {
   name: "Test1",
   images: [
   {
    name: "test1img1",
    shot_type: "product"
   },
   {
    name: "test1img2",
    shot_type: "product"
   }]
}]

var searchObject = { shot_type: 'product' };


//   V------------ implementation here
var foundObject = _.reduce(
    filteredVariants, 
    (last, next) => last || _.find(next.images, searchObject), 
    null
);


console.log(foundObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible, and probably less confusing in plain js :

```js
const filteredVariants =
[
  {
     name: "Test0",
     images: [{name: "test0img1", shot_type: "swatch"}]
  },
  {
     name: "Test1",
     images: [
         {name: "test1img1", shot_type: "product"},
         {name: "test1img2", shot_type: "product"}
     ]
  }
]
// compare an object to a given model.
function compare(object, model){
    for(str in model)
      if(object[str] != model[str])
        return false;
    return true;
}
// gets all 'images" properties, iterates over them and returns the first
// one that matches. returns null if nothing works
function findImage(array, model){
  for(var i in filteredVariants){
    var obj = filteredVariants[i],
     images = obj.images;
     for(var j in images){
       if(compare(images[j], model))
         return images[j];
     }
  }
  return null;
}

console.log(findImage(filteredVariants, {shot_type: "product"}));
```